# Is there a reason why I can't see any projects in this hub?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Using the DM API, I'm collecting projects from various hubs.
However, with only one of the hubs, in which my UserId has access to see a project in A360, I am not able to see the project with the DataManagement API.

Calling:
"/project/v1/hubs/" + hubId + "/projects"

Receving back: 200/OK
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"links":{"self":{"href":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/a.YnVzaW5lc3M6cGZsdWdlcmFyY2hpdGVjdHM0/projects"}},"data":[]}

Comment: Note: this is actually happening on 2 out of 6 hubs.

Comment: I'm checking with the development team... Could be an issue with the API if you can see something from A360 UI.

Comment: @Matt, was this resolved?

Comment: Our customer is no longer connected to this hub, and no other hubs have exhibited the issue.